# What's the next step after creating controller and model in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a controller and a model for my application. I want to get the data in json format. Where can I see my output? If I run the controller it doesn't respond. I am listing the files. Finally I want to get data from the `products` table from database in json format. What to do to get my data?

My Controller:

```
class ShoppingDemo < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists=Product.all;
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @lists}
    end
   end

   def show
    @products = products.find(params[:prod_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

end


My Model:

class product < Activerecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :price, :discount, :qty_available
end

show.html.erb


<p>
  <b>model_name:</b>
  <%= @products.model_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Brand_name:</b>
  <%= @products.brand_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Price:</b>
  <%= @products.price %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Discount:</b>
  <%= @products.discount %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Quantity:</b>
  <%= @products.qty_available %>
</p>
```

Comment: Did you start the server with `rails server` on the command line?

Comment: yes i did.. then i added ShoppingDemo to the url. It shows 'No route matches [GET] "/ShoppingDemo"'.. what to do now??

Comment: http://railsforzombies.org/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your query in show method is completely wrong.

Write show method like following:

```
def show
  @products = Product.find(params[:prod_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
  end
end
```

And write `<%= @products.to_json %>` in your show.html.erb. 

Otherwise you can check by adding the **`.json`** extension in the url. Eg: `http://localhost:3000/shopping_demos/1.json`

Comment: Thank u for giving answer to me...what is this '1.json'?? json is for json format.. then what is 1 here??

Comment: 1 is your 'prod_id'. For the reference I have given for you.

Comment: k k... Do i need to change anything in routes.rb file??

Comment: It gives ROUTING ERROR..The error is 'No route matches [GET] "/ShoppingDemo/PR1.json"'

Comment: sorry to ask this..what is the above one?? where i have to edit this one??

Comment: Go to your routes.rb file in config folder, and add the above line which I have sent before, at the next line of class.

Comment: I did it.. but it shows the error as 'uninitialized constant ShoppingDemosController'...

Comment: For a question, is there any reason to create ShoppingDemo Controller?

Comment: And why don't you use Products controller directly, which takes you very speed every where.

Comment: the controller what i showed above is named as 'ShoppingDemo'.. Thats it. There is no file named with 'ShoppingDemosController'

Comment: No, the controller should not be seemed so.Do you have products contrller?

Comment: no... I have only controller file that showed above.. No other file.. Do i need to create it?

Comment: Ok, I understood. But you have product.rb file na in your app/model/ folder? Id it is there. Give me the class name of that file.

Comment: name of the model file is 'products.rb' and the data in that file is class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :price, :discount, :qty_available
end

Comment: write the line in your command prompt: `rails g controller products`

Comment: yes.. done.. it generated a file named products_controller.rb

Comment: please come to `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails` link. Lets chat there.

Comment: i dont have much reputations to talk there. i have only 17 rep's .. or else  if dont mind u give your mob num?? i will call you... later all we can remove your num from here..plz

Comment: Ok.. my mail id is: ch_pavankumar@sify.com

Comment: But i think the code what i have written is sufficent to get the data from database na?

Answer (score 0):

Write the following inside products_controller.rb file.

```
  def index
   @products = Product.all

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
   end
  end
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @product }
     end
  end
```

In your routes.rb file add the following line.
`resources :products`

And go ahead accordingly.

I could find you are not much aware of ruby on rails. Please have a look on the document.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: thank u so much.. then about the html pages.. do i run localhost:3000/products_controller ??

Comment: No pawan. Run as `localhost:3000/products`

Comment: it shows error as: 'NameError in ProductsController#index' when i use localhost:3000/products

Comment: write `render :text => params and return false` under the `def index` method

Comment: it gives undefined local variable or method `params' for ProductsController:Class

Comment: run $rake routes | grep product and check the routes available. this will surely give an idea

Comment: yeah it shows diferent methods and their formats for GET and POST

Comment: i used url as localhost:3000/products/PR1.json

Comment: I suggest you to please go through the rails guide, and API. Then you will get good confidence. Making simple rails application with associations is a matter of 10 mnts. I think you spent much time instead.

Comment: Sorry dear, I am leaving office right now. Do yourself it carefully for today, I wish you won't get any error. My suggestion is that make a sample application in rails which will get you cleared. The rails guide will give complete reference.